# my background in css that work on style in html but not work when stay on css file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the `background` of a HTML Page. It works with the `style` tag in my HTML's `head` but not in my CSS file.

## This works

[image: This works]

## This does not work

[image: This does not work]

Note: "on css file that can display my background on firebug"

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Please read up on [ask]. Then come back and edit your question so that it doesn't contain pictures of code but instead a Stack Snippet as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the style change the img url to : `../img/02.jpg`. It's because the image folder isn't in the css folder, you need to go up the directory using `..`

Comment: Mark the question as solved if you don't have any more questions, also next time try searching more :)